# How to get unlimited queries from google custom search api

Tags: android, xml, json, api

I want to use google custom search api for my next android app . can anyone tell that is it possible to get unlimited queries per day from the pai . I am ready to pay whatever they charge . and i want to use the api for a single domain.
Thank You

Answer (score 3):

You will need to sign up for billing:

> Any usage beyond the free usage quota will fail if you are not signed
>   up for billing. Once you have enabled billing, you will continue to
>   receive 100 free queries per day. However, you will be billed for all
>   additional requests at the rate of $5 per 1000 queries, for up to
>   10,000 queries per day. If you need additional quota, please request
>   additional quota from the console.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview#pricing

Comment: I know this but what I want to know is that what they charge us exactly for unlimited queries for single domain

Comment: You have to pay per quota. I don't think you can simply pay a flat fee for unlimited queries.

Comment: Do you have any idea how much will they charge me for around 300000 queries per day

Comment: No, I have no idea. You'll need to contact Google.

Comment: Google offers no price breaks, so 300,000 queries per day at a rate of $5 per 1000 is $5 x 300 = $1,500 per day.

Comment: If I subscribe to Google Site Search http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/products/gss.html#pricing_content , will the API quotas for Custom Search be raised to the Site Search limit?