# How does copyscape protect itself from captcha?

Tags: php

www.copyscape.com searches duplicate content using google api. How is it possible?
If I use file_get_contents($google_search_url), it works. But after some search it stops working. I have found some places where it is told that compyscape hide it's ip to google. But then how they receive data from google.

Comment: [How to get unlimited queries from google custom search api](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9853749)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get unlimited queries from google custom search api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853749/how-to-get-unlimited-queries-from-google-custom-search-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copyscape not uses Google API instead it uses Google search it does a simple curl request to http://www.google.com/search?q=Search Keywords here. Then uses regexp patterns to find title, descriptions and links and shows to user. But this strictly violates Google terms of service which can also get them ban, so they uses proxies(or any other ip hiding method) to hide their ip for each search.

Comment: could you please share a simple code of (how to search google hiding ip?)